# RESTful design of authentication in 2 ways

Tags: rest, restful-authentication, restful-architecture, restful-url, api-design

If we had 1 way to authenticate, it will be like

```
POST /sessions
{"email": "user1@domain.com", "password":"12345678"}
```

But how to do it if we have second way to authenticate with social network?

It could be the same verb and path

```
POST /sessions
{"social_network": "facebok", "access_token":"qqqwwweeerrtt"}
```

But now I can't enforce that if email is passed than password also is required.

Comment: What do you mean with second way?

Comment: @Benedikt I have edited my question

Answer (score 0):

You could inspect the request body. The two JSON bodies are different enough to base the decision between the two methods on them.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would make more sense to handle Provider authentication on a separate endpoint (& resource, implicitly):

`POST /providerSessions`

```
{
 "social_network": "facebok",
 "access_token": "qqqwwweeerrtt"
}
```